# Vue installation is failing due to a package version mismatch - how to fix?

Tags: npm, vue.js, codesandbox

Here's the error message:

```
Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@2.5.2
- vue-template-compiler@2.5.13

This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for both.
If you are using vue-loader@>=10.0, simply update vue-template-compiler.
If you are using vue-loader@<10.0 or vueify, re-installing vue-loader/vueify should bump vue-template-compiler to the latest.

    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/test-dev/vue-test/node_modules/vue-template-compiler/index.js:8:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/test-dev/vue-test/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/parser.js:1:80)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)

 @ ./src/router/index.js 4:0-38
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi ./build/dev-client ./src/index.js

> Listening at http://localhost:8080
```

I tried both suggestions: update and re-install. Neither seemed to help.

Here are links to the codesandbox where I set up a working demo. I downloaded the sample as a package from codesandbox (see the download button on the first link) and then ran `npm install` locally (Mac OS X Sierra).

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/1rxq4j1on3

Demo:
https://1rxq4j1on3.codesandbox.io/Sort

Comment: The error message assumes that is the compiler which is behind in version, but actually it's vue. `vue`'s version in the downloaded Codesandbox's `package.json` is a fixed one, try adding `^` before it, so npm can install the latest: `"vue": "^2.5.2"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vue and vue template compiler must use the same version.

latest vue version is : 2.5.13

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue

```
npm install vue
```

latest template compiler version: 2.5.13

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-template-compiler

```
npm install vue-template-compiler
```

add the same version of each to your package.json or install via command line

Comment: This is correct but I think it's important to note that I had to downgrade view, not upgrade vue-template-compiler. The latter idea didn't work.